# parse Json response in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

The response of the call from WebService is as follows:

```
{
    "mobilenumber": "09999999999", 
    "service": "1" , 
    "id": "1"
}
```

How do I parse received Json into objects?

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: Retrofit parses the Json to object out of the box, You have to add a Gson Converter while setting up Retrofit, which I think you would have added. :)

Comment: What's the issue....clarify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `LoginResult` model like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
    
public class LoginResult {
    
    @SerializedName("mobilenumber")
    @Expose
    private String mobilenumber;
    
    @SerializedName("service")
    @Expose
    private String service;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    
    public String getMobilenumber() {
        return mobilenumber;
    }
    
    public void setMobilenumber(String mobilenumber) {
        this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;
    }
    
    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }
    
    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
}
```

Then, your Retrofit `onResponse()` method should be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        
        LoginResult result = response.body();

        String mobileNumber = result.getMobilenumber();
        String service = result.getService();
        String id = result.getId();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you how to parse the json.

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
     if (response.isSuccessful()) {
       JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(yourresponse);
       String mobilenumber = jsonobject.getString("mobilenumber");
       String service = jsonobject.getString("service");
       String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
            }
```

Comment: JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject("yourresponse"); What exactly is yourresponse

Comment: yeah you should pass your response which you are getting from server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's ResponseBody type.

A Converter which uses Gson for serialization to and from JSON. A default Gson instance will be created or one can be configured and passed to the GsonConverterFactory to further control the serialization.

Add to gradle;

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:latest.version'


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.xxx.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```